# Error 500 when I try to connect MySql with php's mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, mysqli

I have written below `php` code to connect MySQL DB:

```
    <?php
// Connect to MySQL
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "A11b22c33&";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

However this code fails to make any connection. All I am getting is below error:

```
currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

However if I remove the connection portion of my code then my `php` file working perfectly, i.e. I am getting *echo* as *'Connected successfully'*

```
<?php
// Connect to MySQL
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "A11b22c33&";


echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Can somebody help me to understand what went wrong? I have checked username and password, and they are perfect

Comment: are you using xampp?, the second one is just an echo that happens regardless since there is no check.

Comment: What are you using for a web server? Apache?

Comment: I am using nginx as my web server

Comment: 500 errors should get logged to your webserver error log (depending on your nginx config). Might be at /usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log or somewhere in /var/log/nginx/

Comment: I checked /var/log/nginx/ and found this : "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /var/www/html/Data.php:3

Comment: I now installed mysqlnd using apt-get install php-mysqlnd now it looks fine.

Comment: No real passwords please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just installed `mysqlnd`  using `apt-get install php-mysqlnd`, and it works fine.